# Database 28 cannot be autostarted during server shutdown or startup

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2008 on a PC with xxx.xxx.x.200. When I connected to the server from another machine(say xxx.xxx.x.81) using SQL Server Management Studio, I get the following error.

```
 TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Database 28 cannot be autostarted during server shutdown or startup. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 904)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.3042&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=904&LinkId=20476
```

To know more, I tried the same with another client machine (say xxx.xxx.x.92), it works well. **WHY** does it behave like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might have a corrupt database.  Connect with a query window and query sys.databases to see which database is database 28 (unless that's the name) and run DBCC CHECKDB against that database to see what the actual problem is.  Also check the ERRORLOG file on the SQL Server to see what it says.